# Jquery click function is not working for dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I am using `$.each` to create the button with each array object. I also tried to give each button a specific id, so I can do click event for further coding, but now I don't know why all the buttons are not functioning. Did I miss some code?

```js
var questlist = [{
  "startdate": "2015-01-08",
  "questitem": [

    {
      "questid": "1",
      "gifttype": "stars",
      "quantity": 10,
      "questname": "One",
      "queststatus": "done"
    }, {
      "questid": "2",
      "gifttype": "stars",
      "quantity": 50,
      "questname": "Two",
      "queststatus": "ready"
    }, {
      "questid": "3",
      "gifttype": "stars",
      "quantity": 100,
      "questname": "Three",
      "queststatus": "complete"
    }, {
      "questid": "4",
      "gifttype": "stars",
      "quantity": 120,
      "questname": "Four",
      "queststatus": "done"
    }, {
      "questid": "5",
      "gifttype": "stars",
      "quantity": 220,
      "questname": "Five",
      "queststatus": "ready"
    },

  ]

}];
questitemlist(questlist);

function questitemlist() {
  var callquest = "<div class='questlist_container'>" +
    "<div id='call_questitem'></div>" +

    "</div>";

  $("#call_quest").append(callquest);
  var questlistobj = questlist[0].questitem;
  $.each(questlistobj, function(i, obj) {
    if (obj.queststatus == "ready") {
      var questlist_item_button = "<input type='button' id='questlist_item_button_go" + obj.questid + "' class='questlist_item_button' id='questlist_item_button' value='GO !'/>";
      $("#questlist_item_button_go" + obj.questid).click(function() {
        alert("go");

      });
      console.log("#questlist_item_button_go" + obj.questid);
    } else if (obj.queststatus == "done") {
      var questlist_item_button = "<input type='button' id='questlist_item_button_reward" + obj.questid + "' class='questlist_item_button' id='questlist_item_button' value='REWARD !'/>";
      $("#questlist_item_button_reward" + obj.questid).click(function() {
        alert("reward");

      });
    } else if (obj.queststatus == "complete") {
      var questlist_item_button = "<label class='questlist_item_complete'><img class='questlist_item_img' src='img/check.png'/></label>";

    }

    var questlist_item = "<div class='questlist_item'>" +
      questlist_item_button +
      "<label class='questlist_item_questname'>" + obj.questname + "</label>" +
      "<label class='questlist_item_gifttype'>" + obj.gifttype + " " + obj.quantity + " " + "</label>" +
      "</div>";

    $("#call_questitem").append(questlist_item);

  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="call_quest"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `click()` function you can call on the elements which have **direct binding**. Direct binding will only attach event handler which are present at the time of DOM loading i.e. static elements.

**If there are elements created after DOM is loaded, then not all the events associated with them would be triggered if you have not attached the event handlers correctly.**

And when you create dynamic elements that means they are being created after DOM is loaded and they were not present at the time of **direct binding**, so you can not call directly `click()` on that.

if you want to get `click` functionality on dynamic created elements, you'll have create a **delegated binding** by using [**on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/). This you can achieve by adding a `.on` handler to a static parent element.

```
Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that          
are added to the document at a later time.
```

Change this line

```
$("#questlist_item_button_reward" + obj.questid).click(function() {
    alert("reward");
});
```

to

```
$("#call_questitem").on("click", "#questlist_item_button_reward" + obj.questid, function() {
    alert("reward");
});
```

And do the same for the `go` button as well.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fvr5njyy/)

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the dynamic id with `questlist_item_button`.

```
<input 
    type='button' 
    id='questlist_item_button_go"+obj.questid+"'  
    class='questlist_item_button' 
    id='questlist_item_button' <!-- REMOVE ME --> 
    value='GO !'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

That was because your DOM will be created on the fly. So you have to use delegate with jQuery:

Bind click event on document with selected id:

```
$(document).on('click', '#questlist_item_button_go'+obj.questid, function(){
     // your action here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.on()` function to attach an event for dynamically created elements.

**EXAMPLE**

```
$(document).on('click', '#DYNAMIC_ELEMENT_ID', function(){
     // your action here
});
```