# jQuery. How do I select live created element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here is the code:

```
    helpers.ajaxModuleFormRequest('blockcallback', $(this), function() {
        var timer = $('[data-timer]');
        var seconds = timer.data('timer');

        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (seconds == 0) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            timer.text(seconds);
            seconds--;
        }, 1000);
    });
```

helper.ajaxModuleFormRequest() does an AJAX-request and then in $.ajax.done() method calls callback-function specified in 3rd param.

`<div data-timer="20"></div>` is inserted in DOM live $.ajax.done() method and I want to select it to start the timer. But the code doesn't work, `$('[data-timer]').length` returns 0. How can I fix this?

Comment: similer question [selector for dynamic elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976739/jquery-click-function-is-not-working-for-dynamic-elements/27976810#27976810)

Comment: To understand the issue, we need to know more about how you're manipulating the div. I have created [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0vpatwgc/) from your code and it works fine.

Comment: There'is no div in DOM on page load. It is inserted in DOM after AJAX-request.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified example, which inserts a `<div>` dynamically and then starts the timer:

**Html:**

```
<html>
<head>Testpage</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
{
    $('body').append('<div data-timer="20"></div>');
    var timer = $('[data-timer]');
    var seconds = timer.data('timer');
    if (seconds!==undefined)
    {
        alert(seconds);
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (seconds == 0) {
                alert('elapsed!');
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            timer.text(seconds);
            seconds--;
        }, 1000);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please specify a timer value!");
    }
}
```

Note that initially the `<div>` is not there, it is inserted dynamically via

```
$('body').append('<div data-timer="20"></div>');
```

If you want to test whether it tests correctly for existance of the timer value, comment the line above, i.e.

```
// $('body').append('<div data-timer="20"></div>');
```

and you'll get the alert message "Please specify a timer value!".

Try it on jsfiddle:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0vpatwgc/2/)

```js
{
    $('body').append('<div data-timer="20"></div>');
    var timer = $('[data-timer]');
    var seconds = timer.data('timer');
    if (seconds!==undefined)
    {
        alert(seconds);
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (seconds == 0) {
                alert('elapsed!');
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            timer.text(seconds);
            seconds--;
        }, 1000);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please specify a timer value!");
    }
}
```

```html
<head>Testpage</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```